# ruby stuck in 1.8.7 on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-11.10

Today I learned that Ubuntu is bundled with Ruby 1.8.7.  I want 1.9.2, but getting Ruby 1.9.2 working has been frustrating.

First, note that Ruby 1.9.2 is already installed on my system.

Here's what's happening:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

$ rvm list
rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64 ]

$ printenv PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

$ which rvm
/usr/bin/rvm
```

Comment: why didn't you install rvm locally as recommended?

Answer (score 1):

RVM hasn't initialized correctly. Your path should show RVM's managed directories first.

Have you added the RVM initializer to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`, and have you restarted your shell session or logged out then back in?

Have you followed the installation and troubleshooting directions at http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install ?

Please append the output of `rvm info` to your question.

Normally RVM would install inside your `~/.rvmrc` directory for a single-user sandbox. Because it is at `/usr/bin/rvm` that tells me you installed it as `root` or did a `sudo` when you installed it. I highly recommend not bothering with multi-user RVM unless you have a really good reason, and instead use the single-user install.

Comment: ah, that must be the problem.  I'll try installing it locally.

Comment: It *might* be the problem. What does `rvm info` show? It reveals all.